# Differences between "<command> & disown" and "nohup <command> & disown"

Tags: command-line, bash, nohup, background-process

This is my understanding about the usage of `&`, `disown` and `nohup`:

- `<command>`: runs the process within the Terminal's current `bash` instance, **in the foreground** (i.e. the process is listed as a `bash` foreground job and `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are still **bound to the terminal**); **not immune to hangups**;
- `<command> &`: runs the process within the Terminal's current `bash` instance, **in the background** (i.e. the process is listed as a `bash` background job and `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are still **bound to the terminal**); **not immune to hangups**;
- `<command> & disown`: runs the process within the Terminal's current `bash` instance, **in the background**, but the process is **detached from the `bash`'s jobs' list** (i.e. the process is not listed as a `bash` foreground / background job and `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are still **bound to the terminal**); **immune to hangups**;
- `nohup <command> & disown`: runs the process within the Terminal's current `bash` instance, **in the background**, but the process is **detached from the `bash`'s jobs' list** (i.e. the process is not listed as a `bash` foreground / background job and `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are **not** still **bound to the terminal**);**immune to hangups**;

So, aside from `nohup <command> & disown` blocking `stdin` and redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to `nohup.out` by default, it seems to me like it can be considered totally equivalent to `<command> & disown`.

Is the above all correct? Any misconception?

Comment: What do you mean by "immune to hangups" and "not immune to hangups"?

Comment: @chaos I mean that terminating / killing the parent `bash` instance won't kill the process

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your understanding is basically correct. Both `disown` and `nohup` are used to allow you to exit a running shell session without stopping running jobs. Some clarifications:

- There's no reason to run `nohup command & disown`, `nohup` will already disown it for you.
- `nohup` is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nohup.html) while `disown` [is not](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01). This means that while many shells (e.g. `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`) have it, others (for example `tcsh`, `csh`, `dash` and `sh`) won't have it.
- `disown` can be used *after* a command has been launched while `nohup` must be used before.

As far as I can tell, the actual effect of the two commands is the same. They each have features that the other lacks (see `help disown` and `man nohup`) but their basic function is the same, yes.

For a far more detailed discussion of these tools and the differences between them, have a look at the answers here:

- [Do `disown -h` and `nohup` work effectively the same?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/484276/22222)
- [Difference between nohup, disown and &](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/22222)

Comment: `Nohup` and `disown` are not the same thing and using both commands together is NOT redundant. See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and) for an in depth description

Comment: I've not had good luck with nohup when spawning processes from C++ and C#, however `& disown` has had good results.

Answer (score 7):

Your first to third points seem alright, although `stdin, stdout and stderr are still bound to the terminal` is not a right notion. `stdin` is always bound to terminal in the sense that you would always input the file name to a command via terminal or ways using terminal. `stdout and stderr are still bound to the terminal` is alright.

Your have `stdin, stdout and stderr are not still bound to the terminal` in the fourth point which is not right as mentioned in my earlier paragraph. Also here you are using `/dev/null` as the input file to the `command`, for example if the command is `cat`, you are using it as `cat /dev/null`.

The command on your 5th point is not correctly put, you used `nohup <command> & disown`, while using any one of `nohup` or `disown` the other one is not needed. Their purposes are the same (to ignore the `SIGHUP`) but they function in a bit different way. So the command can be simplified as `nohup <command> &`.