# Launch command in gnome-terminal, then close gnome-terminal without ending executed command?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, yad

I have a semi oddball thing I'm tinkering with. I'm looking for a way to make launching MPV (video player) to video links easier. MPV's default behavior is to either launch `mpv https://url.of.video` in terminal, or drag/drop the URL to the MPV window. I don't find this kosher being a keyboard centric person. Instead I'd like to initiate a popup box, paste the URL, hit enter, and have MPV launch the video to that URL. That way I could tie this command to a keyboard shortcut, making the full process crazy easy. I have this complete, but with one minor papercut -- the gnome-terminal window hangs around. It's a simple one liner:

```
URL=$(yad --entry) && gnome-terminal -- bash -c "mpv $URL"
```

If I launch that command, I get a popup box thanks to YAD. At this point I paste the URL, hit enter, and in 1-2 seconds an MPV window opens to that video. Awesome. Exactly what I wanted.

The paper cut I mentioned is the fact that gnome-terminal stays running. Not a massive issue, but I'd like to figure out if there's a way for this command above to launch gnome-terminal, call upon MPV, append the variable (URL), and then have gnome-terminal close itself without ending the video stream.

Curious if anybody has any ideas. Thanks much!

Comment: Why do you need gnome terminal in that command in the first place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Solution to your problem

The right solution here is to omit calling `gnome-terminal` and `bash` and even setting an unneeded variable in the first place, all of that is not needed in your case:

```
mpv -- "$(yad --entry)"
```

I added quotes to handle the URL correctly, this ensures it can contain e.g. whitespaces and ampersand signs (`&`) and the command still works. `--` tells `mpv` to stop looking for options and treats whatever you choose to give it as an argument instead. Image the common case where you have a file named `--version` in the directory you start mpv from and just enter this filename, how can `mpv` know whether to show you its version string or open the file?

#### Answer to your question

`nohup` or `disown` can be used to detach a process from the shell that started it, see [Differences between "<command> & disown" and "nohup <command> & disown"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611968/differences-between-command-disown-and-nohup-command-disown).

In your case the correct solution would be:

```
gnome-terminal -e nohup mpv -- "$(yad --entry)"
```

However for a much better solution see above.

Comment: Much thanks for your insight. Works great and simple. :)