# close one specific GNOME Terminal command

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I run a loop like this (duration one hour):

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --geometry=50x30 --working-directory=/$HOME/TEST --title terminal1 -e  ' sh -c "./FirstAPP; exec bash"'
while true; do
    if [ ! pgrep SecondAPP ]; then
        gnome-terminal --geometry=50x30 --working-directory=/$HOME/TEST --title terminal2 -e  ' sh -c "./SecondAPP; exec bash"'
        for ((i=0; i<3600; i+=5)); do
            sleep 5
            if [ ! pgrep SecondAPP ]; then
                break
            fi
        done
        killall -9 SecondAPP > /dev/null 2>&1 
    # Iwant here a command that closes the gnome-terminal "terminal2"
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

I run this loop and I noticed that in the terminal2 the process got killed but the terminal stays open. Is there a flag or something to close that terminal2?

Or is my implementation wrong?

PS. I am a newbie in Ubuntu, I looked up closing [specific terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973114/launch-command-in-gnome-terminal-then-close-gnome-terminal-without-ending-execu), however I dont think it apllies to my case.

Comment: You don't think it applies to your use case, but have you tried the suggested solution?

Comment: yes, I tried it. the terminal still opens, I added the nohup flag to the gnome-terminal command

Comment: Do you really need these to be running in a terminal though? Why are you opening 2 terminals? This only makes your life more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are killing the program `SeondApp`, but you are not killing the terminal it is running in. The two are separate things. For example, this is the process tree of running `gedit` in a terminal:

```
$ gedit &
[1] 13064
$ pstree -s 13064
systemd───systemd───gnome-terminal-───bash───gedit───4*[{gedit}]
```

Ignore the `systemd`, that's the `init` process, everything running on your machine is a child of `systemd`. Then, what you see there is that `gnome-terminal`    has launched `bash` which then runs `gedit`. If you now kill `gedit`, that won't affect its parents. However, if you kill one of the parents, that will also kill the child.

Normally, what you would do is to use `$!`, a special variable that holds the PID of the last process launched to the background. Unfortunately, that doesn't with `gnome-terminal` which seems to have some sort of complicated launching procedure:

```
$ gnome-terminal &
[1] 23861
$ ps aux | grep 23861
terdon   24341  0.0  0.0   8684  2348 pts/11   S+   10:59   0:00 grep --color 23861
$ pgrep gnome-terminal
23866
```

As you can see above, gnome-terminal seem to re-launch itself after launching and uses a different PID. No idea why, but another good reason to use a different terminal.

So, since the standard approach won't work, we need a workaround. What you can do is use `kill -$PID` which will kil all processes in the process group (from `man kill`):

```
-n  where n is larger than 1.  All processes in process  group  n  are
    signaled.   When  an argument of the form '-n' is given, and it is
    meant to denote a process group, either a signal must be specified
    first,  or  the argument must be preceded by a '--' option, other‐
    wise it will be taken as the signal to send.
```

Putting all this together, here's a working version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --geometry=50x30 --working-directory=/$HOME/TEST --title terminal1 \
               -e  ' sh -c "./FirstAPP; exec bash"'
while true; do
    if ! pgrep SecondAPP; then
        gnome-terminal --geometry=50x30 --working-directory=/$HOME/TEST \
            --title terminal2 -e  'SecondAPP' &
        for ((i=0; i<3600; i+=5)); do
          sleep 5
          if ! pgrep SecondAPP; then
            break
          fi
        done
        ## Now, get the PID of SecondAPP
        pid=$(pgrep SecondAPP)
        ## Using -$pid will kill all process in the process group of $pid, so
        ## it will kill SecondAPP and its parent process, the terminal.
        kill -- -$pid
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

Note that I also remove the `[ ]` around `! pgrep` since that was wrong syntax.

---

I don't see why you are launching terminals at all though. Here's the same idea, without terminals:

```
#!/bin/bash

$HOME/TEST/FirstAPP
while true; do
    if ! pgrep SecondAPP; then
      #$HOME/TEST/SecondAPP &
      SecondAPP &
      pid=$!
        for ((i=0; i<3600; i+=5)); do
          sleep 5
          if ! pgrep SecondAPP; then
            break
          fi
        done
        kill $pid
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

---

Finally, this feels like a strange way of doing things. You might want to ask a new question, explain what you are trying to do and why and we can see if we can find a simpler approach for whatever it is you need.

Comment: thanks I'll give it a try, I use terminals, because they need to show me some progress within that terminal, however I need to kill them every hour

Comment: @user1616685 ah, I see. I would still probably use `xterm` instead of `gnome-terminal` though. Gnome-terminal is very complex and heavy, and you don't need any of its fancy features here.

Comment: I tried to use xterm, however flags like working directory are not working

Comment: @user1616685 yeah, you'd do it with `-e "cd $HOME/TEST && ./FirstAPP` or even just `$HOME/TEST/FirstAPP`, if you don't really need to run it from that dir.

Comment: thanks, I execute the xterm command, but the code stays at that line, opens the firstAPP and paused there, when I CTRL+C then the code goes on.

Comment: xterm -e  ' sh -c "./FirstAPP; exec bash"'

Comment: @user1616685 that seems odd. Although if the terminal stays there, it's because you tell it to `exec bash` which doesn't seem necessary at all. But please ask a new question if you want more help with this.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115846/xterm-in-bash-stops-script-from-executing