# xterm in bash stops script from executing

Tags: bash, scripts, xterm

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

xterm -e ' sh -c "$HOME/TEST/FirstAPP --test;" exec bash'
## script opens the xterm and stops until I press CTRL+C
while true; do
....
```

this question is related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115475/close-one-specific-gnome-terminal-command)

Why does the script stop at this place? I need to get the xterm called and running and then continue with the code having FirstApp running.

I used the gnome-terminal without problems.

Comment: Where exactly does it stop? And what does FirstApp do? Does it ever exit? How is the terminal when it is "stopped"? Does it display a prompt? Why are you running `exec bash`?

Comment: it starts a process, that does not end, but sometimes fails, so that is why it need to be killed and restartd every hour.

Comment: I put exec bash in order to go on with the script

Comment: But if `FirstAPP` doesn't end, how would anything else continue? Your command means "run `FirstAPP` _and when that finishes_, run `exec bash`". If that is not what you want, please [edit] and clarify what behavior you are expecting. You can also ping me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) if you want and we can see if we can sort it out.

Comment: ok, I edit the question. I need to call the app and then go on in the script

Comment: Have you tried running the terminal in the background?

Comment: thank you the "&" was the key... I am a linux newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your script to run a command and then continue executing, you need to tun the command in the background (`&`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/22222). So, change your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

xterm -e 'sh -c "$HOME/TEST/FirstAPP --test;"' &
## script opens the xterm and stops until I press CTRL+C
while true; do
....
```

That will launch the `xterm` command in the background, keeping the terminal open and `FirstAPP` running, and will then continue onto the other lines of your script.

The reason it worked with `gnome-terminal` is because when you run `gnome-terminal`, it apparently forks itself and returns control to the shell you launched it from. You can see this with `strace`:

```
$ strace -e clone gnome-terminal 
clone(child_stack=0x7fef6e44db30, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fef6e44e9d0, tls=0x7fef6e44e700, child_tidptr=0x7fef6e44e9d0) = 9534
clone(child_stack=0x7fef6dc4cb30, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fef6dc4d9d0, tls=0x7fef6dc4d700, child_tidptr=0x7fef6dc4d9d0) = 9535
# watch_fast: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
clone(child_stack=0x7fef6d391b30, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fef6d3929d0, tls=0x7fef6d392700, child_tidptr=0x7fef6d3929d0) = 9540
# unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (active: 0, establishing: 1)
# watch_established: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (establishing: 0)
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Note the calls to `clone` which, as explained in `man clone` does:

```
   clone() creates a new process, in a manner similar to fork(2).
```

So, unlike most programs, `gnome-terminal` will make a clone of itself when launched. The normal way of launching something and then continuing with something else is to use `&` to launch it in the background.