# cron pipe to file relative path not working

Tags: cron

I'm trying to debug why my cron job is not working

Here's what I have so far:

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> /tmp/test_cron_hello <-- WORKS
* * * * * cd ~/bot-v2 & date >> /tmp/test_cron_hello <-- WORKS
* * * * * cd ~/bot-v2 & date >> logs/cron.txt <-- DOES NOT WORK
```

I know that ~/bot-v2/logs/cron.txt is a valid file and folder and I am running crontab -e as root.

Comment: Btw: `>>` is not pipe but [I/O Redirection](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), This is a pipe: `command | other_command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need `&&` instead of `&`.**

---

Explanation:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell. *(man bash)*

`&` will send the command (`cd ~/bot-v2`)  to background and it will run in a **subshell**, so for the next command `date >> relative/path/to/file` you are not changing directories at all.

Try `cd ~/bot-v2 &` in terminal  and you will see that your current shell won't change directories.

---

See also:

- [What does the & mean when used in the end of a bash script?](https://superuser.com/questions/358491/what-does-the-mean-when-used-in-the-end-of-a-bash-script)
- [Differences between "<command> & disown" and "nohup <command> & disown"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611968/differences-between-command-disown-and-nohup-command-disown)
- [What is the purpose of “&&” in a shell command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command)