# How to start deatached process from terminal

Tags: command-line

I downloaded and installed Unityhub and I have to click on the file to run it. I would like to have a command in terminal to run it.
For example I start my VScode simply typing `code` in terminal. I want to start UnityHub by typing something like `unity-hub` in terminal.

I created symlink so I can run it by typing `unity-hub`. But the process is attached to the current terminal. I tried `nohup unity-nub &` but i get unwanted output like

```
$ nohup unity-hub &
[1] 21947
$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

I would like to mimic the "code" behaviour when it starts an application as if I clicked on its file. Without any input in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
unity-hub &>/dev/null & disown
```

More info at this related [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611968/differences-between-command-disown-and-nohup-command-disown)

Answer (score 0):

To get absolutely no output in the current terminal, you can start the `nohup`command inside another `sh` like:

`sh -c "nohup unity-hub &>/dev/null &"`

You may need to specify the full path to `unity-hub` if it's not local to current folder and `sh` (or `bash`) doesn't have it in the `PATH`.

You can also create your custom `.desktop` file to simply launch the app from the apps menu.

See Ubuntu documentation [UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) or this article [How to Create a .Desktop File For Your Application in Linux](https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-desktop-file-linux/)